# returning broken href link when scraping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape IMDB https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250. I want to write a loop to enter each film page by getting all the href attributes. However, the html code returned by urlopen shows broken href attributes (ignoring everythin after the question mark). Here are my code and result. Thank you so much in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250'
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')
table = bs.find('tbody',{'class':'lister-list'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    link = row.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find('a')['href']
    print(link)
```

The result I get is something like this (ignoring everythin after the question mark)

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/web_scraping/bin/python /Users/gracezhou/Python/Python-Projects/scraping/imdb/test.py
/title/tt0111161/
/title/tt0068646/
/title/tt0071562/
/title/tt0468569/
/title/tt0050083/
/title/tt0108052/
/title/tt0167260/
/title/tt0110912/
/title/tt0060196/
/title/tt0120737/
/title/tt0137523/
/title/tt0109830/
```

I wan to receive somethins like this:

```
/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=CPK54FS6SPX9EDAPBSJT&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1
```

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES** Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the request using headers with `User-Agent` in it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")

table = soup.find('tbody',{'class':'lister-list'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    link = row.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find('a')['href']
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1
/title/tt0068646/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_2
/title/tt0071562/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_3
/title/tt0468569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_4
/title/tt0050083/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_5
/title/tt0108052/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_6
/title/tt0167260/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_7
/title/tt0110912/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_8
/title/tt0060196/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_9
/title/tt0120737/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_10
/title/tt0137523/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_11
/title/tt0109830/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_12
/title/tt1375666/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_13
/title/tt0080684/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_14
/title/tt0167261/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_15
/title/tt0133093/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_16
/title/tt0099685/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_17
/title/tt0073486/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_18
/title/tt0047478/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_19
/title/tt0114369/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_20
/title/tt0118799/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_21
/title/tt0317248/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_22
/title/tt0102926/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_23
/title/tt8503618/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_24
/title/tt0038650/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_25
/title/tt0076759/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_26
/title/tt0120815/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_27
/title/tt0245429/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_28
/title/tt6751668/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_29
/title/tt0120689/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_30
/title/tt0816692/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_31
/title/tt0110413/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_32
/title/tt0114814/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_33
/title/tt0056058/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_34
/title/tt0110357/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_35
/title/tt0088763/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_36
/title/tt0253474/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_37
/title/tt0103064/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_38
/title/tt0120586/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_39
/title/tt0027977/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_40
/title/tt0054215/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_41
/title/tt0172495/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_42
/title/tt0021749/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_43
/title/tt0407887/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_44
/title/tt1675434/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_45
/title/tt2582802/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_46
/title/tt0482571/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_47
/title/tt0095327/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_48
/title/tt0064116/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_49
/title/tt0034583/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_50
/title/tt0095765/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_51
/title/tt0047396/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_52
/title/tt0078748/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_53
/title/tt0078788/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_54
/title/tt0209144/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_55
/title/tt0082971/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_56
/title/tt0032553/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_57
/title/tt7286456/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_58
/title/tt0405094/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_59
/title/tt1853728/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_60
/title/tt0050825/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_61
/title/tt0081505/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_62
/title/tt0910970/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_63
/title/tt4154756/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_64
/title/tt0043014/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_65
/title/tt4633694/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_66
/title/tt0119698/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_67
/title/tt0057012/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_68
/title/tt0051201/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_69
/title/tt0364569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_70
/title/tt1345836/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_71
/title/tt0087843/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_72
/title/tt4154796/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_73
/title/tt0090605/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_74
/title/tt5311514/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_75
/title/tt2380307/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_76
/title/tt0169547/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_77
/title/tt0112573/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_78
/title/tt1187043/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_79
/title/tt0082096/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_80
/title/tt0114709/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_81
/title/tt0057565/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_82
/title/tt0086879/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_83
/title/tt0986264/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_84
/title/tt0086190/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_85
/title/tt0361748/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_86
/title/tt0105236/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_87
/title/tt0119217/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_88
/title/tt8267604/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_89
/title/tt0062622/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_90
/title/tt0180093/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_91
/title/tt8579674/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_92
/title/tt0052357/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_93
/title/tt0022100/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_94
/title/tt5074352/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_95
/title/tt0338013/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_96
/title/tt2106476/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_97
/title/tt0033467/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_98
/title/tt0093058/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_99
/title/tt0040522/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_100
/title/tt0066921/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_101
/title/tt0053125/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_102
/title/tt0012349/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_103
/title/tt0208092/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_104
/title/tt0045152/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_105
/title/tt0086250/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_106
/title/tt0075314/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_107
/title/tt0211915/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_108
/title/tt0056172/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=YMF3CFY4HGXT0TT942CP&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_109
...
...
...
```